# Slack: How to produce unicode symbols by typing their code

Tags: slack

How can I produce unicode symbols in a slack chat by typing their code?

As a mathematician, I routinely need to write things like ⨐∅⊋. In some systems I would just use some escape character and use (hex) `'0x2a10', '0x2205', '0x228b', '0x1f4a9'` or (decimal) `10768, 8709, 8843, 128169`.

But how can I do this in slack?

Comment: Hi thorwhalen, this question is not about programming, hence I've voted to close it as off-topic. For what it's worth – if you're using a Mac, CTRL+CMD+SPACE opens up a little menu that lets you select symbols and emojis, works with most, albeit not all apps

Comment: your questions might be better placed here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slack